# how better for me to

Tags: comparison, interrogatives

a. How better for me to learn English than to hang out with you?

b. How faster for me to get there than to come along with you?

Are both of the above sentences grammatically correct?

I think (a) is correct and is idiomatic and (b) isn't...

Would you like to hang around with us?

a1) How better for me to learn English?

===========================

Would you like to come along with us?

b1) How faster for me to get there?

I think here (a1) works and (b1) doesn't...

Comment: It all sounds very *Little Red Riding Hood* to me— "The better to eat you with, my dear!" I'm not saying they're wrong but saying I would far more typically hear and say, "What better way for me to learn English than to hang out with you?" or, "What faster way for me to get there than to come along with you?" "How better...?" maybe, but "How faster...?" that sounds awfully odd to my ear, not that that means it's not a thing, which is why I'm not answering and only commenting, but it's an odd-sounding thing, at least to me.

Comment: *How [comparative]* is archaic. Shakespeare used it in *King Lear*: “How sharper than a serpent's tooth it is To have a thankless child!”  A more modern-idiomatic version would be *How much sharper*.

Comment: Neither of the  sentences provided make sense/are idiomatic.  Can you provide a clearer description of what you intend those phrases to mean (in context) so we can provide you  with an answer as to how to construct them, and explain what is not idiomatic about the ones provided?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if its grammatical or not, but both sentences sound strange...

It would sound better if you add "it would be" and change the order of the phrases and add "much"
I am assuming you are making a statement and not asking a question.

> How much better it would be for me to learn English, than to hang out with you!

The same thing wouldn't work well for "faster", because "How much faster it would be for me" would refer to something else being fast not yourself

> How much faster I would be to get there, than come with you.

Comment: Thank you all. The intended meaning is: What better way is there for me to learn English that to hang out with you.